# Having problems with pointers and using strcmp() in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, strcmp

I'm writing a method that splits a given array into 2 parts. It keeps the first half in the original array and puts the other half into a temporary array using a symbol that marks where the split is. I'm getting erros as follows:

```
Warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
     if(strcmp(input[i], symbol) == 0){
                         ^
In file included from process.c:7:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
            ^
process.c:95:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
       input[i] = NULL;
                ^
process.c:96:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
       while(input[i + 1] != NULL){
                          ^
process.c:98:22: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
         input[i + 1] = NULL;
                      ^
```

Here is my code:

```c
char *splitCommands(char *input, char symbol){
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   char *temp;
   int symbIndex; // where the symbol was
   while(input[i] != NULL){
    if(strcmp(input[i], symbol) == 0){
      symbIndex = i;
      input[i] = NULL;
      while(input[i + 1] != NULL){
        temp[j] = input[i + 1];
        input[i + 1] = NULL;
        i++;
        j++;
      }
      break;
    }

     i++;
  }

   return temp;

}
```

Comment: strcmp is for comparing strings. input[i] and symbol are both single chars. you can just compare them with ==

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do this comparison

```
if (input[i] == symbol)
```

because `input[i]` and `symbol` have type `char` and hence you compare their values, when the are strings you compare addresses which is why you need `strcmp()`.

And

```
input[i + 1] = NULL;
```

is equivalent to

```
input[i + 1] = (void *) 0;
```

hence, you are trying to assign a pointer, to a `char`, which is also wrong, perhaps you mean

```
input[i + 1] = 0;
```

or in a more c-ish fashion

```
input[i + 1] = '\0';
```

Also, the `while` condition, the same problem, just

```
while (input[i])
```

would be enough, if you like your code to be more readable, I personally think that,

```
while (input[i] != '\0')
```

is more readable.

And you can't use `temp` like that because it's uninitialized, you need to allocate space for it, like this

```
temp = malloc(1 + estimatedSizeInBytes);
if (temp == NULL)
    return NULL;

/* add the '\0' terminator */
temp[realSize - 1] = '\0';
```

where `realSize <= estimatedSize`.

You should also remember to `free()` the pointer returned by this function when you finish using it.

Answer (score 0):

`input[i]` and `symbol` are `char`. So campare by `imput[i] == symbol`. And don't forget to allocate memory for `char *tmp`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code but one of the primary problems and reason for your compiler errors is that strcmp() takes two pointers to c style strings as arguments. You are passing two char's to it, instead of pointers.

Another problem is that you're assigning a char to NULL, however NULL should only be used for pointers, not other types like char/int/float. If you're trying to check for the end of a c style string, check if the char is equal to 0 or '\0' instead. You'll probably have to spend more time learning about c style strings and pointers before you can finish this program.

I won't complete your assignment/work for you but I will give you an example of how to use strcmp():

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char String1[4] = "abc";
    char String2[4] = "xyz";

    int Result = strcmp(String1, String2);

    if (Result < 0)
        printf("%s < %s\n", String1, String2);
    if (Result == 0)
        printf("%s = %s\n", String1, String2);
    if (Result > 0)
        printf("%s > %s\n", String1, String2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: abc < xyz

Here's an additional [strcmp() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) from cplusplus.com.